# I have a table in Django with ManyToManyField. Can't figure out how to update a table entry

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, many-to-many

I have a table with posts that can have multiple categories, and a table with categories that can have multiple posts. models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    body = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', related_name='posts', blank=True)
    profile = models.ForeignKey('Profile', verbose_name='User',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='profile')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

---

views.py

```
Сlass ListCategoryView(generic.ListView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        category = kwargs['category']
        posts = Post.objects.filter(categories__name__contains=category).order_by('-created_on')
        context = {
            "category": category,
            "posts": posts
        }
        return render(request, "list_category.html", context)

class ListPostView(generic.ListView):

    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    template_name = 'list_post.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.order_by('-created_on')
        return queryset

class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):

    model = Post
    template_name = 'create_post.html'
    form_class = PostDocumentForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        blog_form = PostDocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if blog_form.is_valid():
            categories = Category.objects.create(name=blog_form.cleaned_data['categories'])
            title = blog_form.cleaned_data.get('title')
            body = blog_form.cleaned_data.get('body')
            profile = request.user.profile
            image = self.get_image(blog_form)
            instance = Post.objects.create(title=title, body=body, profile=profile, image=image)
            instance.categories.set([categories])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/blog/')
        return render(request, 'create_post.html', context={'form': blog_form})

    def get_image(self, form):
        image = form.cleaned_data.get('image')
        return image


class EditPostView(generic.UpdateView):

    form_class = PostDocumentForm
    model = Post
    template_name = 'edit_post.html'
    success_url = '/blog/'
```

forms.py:

```
class CategoryDocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('name',)


class PostDocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    categories = forms.CharField(min_length=3, max_length=100, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'body', 'image', 'categories')
```

I can't figure out how to update the post so that the categories are updated as well.
I looked for many solutions, but none of them helped.
I tried get_or_create, update, delete, then create again, but nothing worked.
Better, as in most social networks - add a tag(here a category) manually, without selecting from the list of possible ones

Comment: Hi Steep27! What do you want to update exactly? The relationship between Category and Post, the data of a single Post or Category? What should be the outcome of your efforts?

Comment: Hello, I want to update categories. I have a form for creating and editing a post, but when I'm on the edit page, when I enter any category(for example 'any') in the category bar, appears an error "Field 'id' expected a number but got 'a'". Fields "name", "body", "image" updated normally, but with field 'categories' I have a problem.

Comment: Could you post your `PostDocumentForm`?

Comment: Updated question, added forms.py

Comment: You need to use a `ModelMultipleChoiceField` instead of a `CharField` for your categories. Django handles updating via this form and tries to update categories with the content of your string - this will not work. Look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield

Comment: but what, if I want to do it, like in most social networks: just add a tag, wihout selecting from the list?

Comment: Now I realize that you want to create categories on the fly by just typing in a category name. So you need that string value. In this case you need to take care of the form handling by yourself. Splitting the string in tokens, creating these categories and attaching to the post instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you:

```
class PostEditView(UpdateView):
     def form_valid(self, form):
        # Take care of creating of updating your post with cleaned data
        # by yourself

        category_tokens = form.cleaned_data['categories'].split()
        categories = set()
        for token in category_tokens:
            try:
                category = Category.objects.get(name=token)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                category = Category.objects.create(name=token)
            
            categories.add(category)

        # now you need to add the categories which are new to this post
        # and delete the categories which do not belong anymore to your post
        current_posts_categories = set(post_instance.categories_set.all())
        categories_to_add = categories - current_posts_categories
        categories_to_delete = current_posts_categories - categories

        # further handling is up to you ...
```